# Remove outliers by condition from list of data frames

Tags: r, lm, outliers

I try to create a function to remove multiple outliers via cooks distance from a list of data frames.
There are some problems at the moment:

1. **Can I formulate part 1 as function?** I tried several things that did not work out. I want to use several different variables for the lm - so it would be great if I could use colnumbers and the regular expression syntax of data frames as input argument.
2. **Part 2** - the filename of the plots are not correct. It takes the first observation in each data frame from the list as filename. How can I correct this?
3. **Part 3:** data frames without the outliers are not created. Function comes to an end after the message is printed. I can't find my mistake.

```
data(iris)
iris.lst <- split(iris[, 1:2], iris$Species)
new_names <- c(paste0(unlist(levels(iris$Species)),"_data"))
for (i in 1:length(iris.lst)) {
  assign(new_names[i], iris.lst[[i]])
}

# Part 1: Then cooks distances
fit <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "_data")), 
       function(x) lm(x[,1] ~ x[,3], data = x))
cooksd <-lapply(fit,cooks.distance)

# Part 2: Plot each data frame with suspected outlier
plots <- function(x){
    jpeg(file=paste0(names(x),".jpeg")) # file names are numbers
    #par(mfrow=c(2,1))    
    plot(x, pch="*", cex=2, main="Influential cases by Cooks distance") #  plot cook's distance
    abline(h = 3*mean(x, na.rm=T), col="red") #  add cutoff line
    text(x=1:length(x)+1, y=x, labels=ifelse(x > 3*mean(x, na.rm=T),
                                                           names(x),""), col="red")
    dev.off()
}
myplots <- lapply(cooksd, plots)

# Part 3: give me new data frames without influential cases
show_influential_cases <- function(x){
    # invisible(cooksd[["n_OG"]] <- lapply(cooksd, length)
    influential <- lapply(x,function(x) names(x)[x > 3*mean(x, na.rm=T)])
    test <- as.data.frame(unlist(influential))[,1]
    test <- as.numeric(test)
}

tested <- show_influential_cases(result)
cleaned_data <- add_new[-tested,] # removing outliers by indexing
```

Could someone please help me to improve my code?
Many thanks,
Nadine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is not a good practice to create multiple dataframes in global environment. Lists always are a better option, they are easy to manage.

Part 1 -

You can combine multiple steps in one `lapply` function. Here in part 1 we apply `lm` and `cooks.distance` function together in the same `lapply` call.

```
master_data <- split(iris[, 1:2], iris$Species)

data <- lapply(master_data, function(x) {
  cooks.distance(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = x))
})
new_names <- paste0(levels(iris$Species),"_data")
names(data) <- new_names
```

Part 2 -

`lapply` does not have access to names of the list, pass them separately and use `Map` to call `plots` function.

```
plots <- function(x, y){
  jpeg(file=paste0(y,".jpeg")) 
  plot(x, pch="*", cex=2, main="Influential cases by Cooks distance")
  abline(h = 3*mean(x, na.rm=T), col="red") #  add cutoff line
  text(x=1:length(x)+1,y=x,labels=ifelse(x > 3*mean(x, na.rm=T),y,""), col="red")
  dev.off()
}
Map(plots, data, names(data))
```

Part 3 -

I am not exactly clear about how you want to perform Part3 but for now I am showing outlier and data separately.

```
remove_influential_cases <- function(x, y){
  inds <- x > 3*mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
  y[!inds, ]
}

result <- Map(remove_influential_cases, data, master_data)
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much.
I try my best to work with lists in future.
The tricky thing about part 3 is that I want to remove the outliers from the original data frame not from the list with the cooks distance.
it is easy for a single data frame... where you just OG_DF[!COOK_DF_INDEX]

Comment: the original data frame has 4 columns in case of iris. So I tried to extract the row.name of each data frame which is identical with cooks-distance data frames. But somehow I fail...

Comment: The cooks distance matrix is identifying outliers

Comment: By filtering according to a test condition (3 x mean CD)

Comment: Hi, I will check it in the evening and let you know if it worked. I haven't come across the Map function so far. I have found an other solution that I will post later on too!

Comment: btw you should ask only one question per post. This post consists of 3 questions.

Comment: The map function is great! 
For the outlier removal I programmed a way that is more intuitive. I wanted to use the row.names for indexing. Might be ugly but okay... updated my question.
Thanks !

Comment: Did you try my answer? What does it return?

Comment: The last part did not work but the rest did. But I wanted I solved the lasts part by myself (see update)